# Access to type T properties of IEnumerable<T> returned from a method called via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a .dll and a console app that uses the said .dll but doesn't reference directly,
it loads it via reflection. The console app calls a method of a class inside the .dll.
The method signature is `IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()`;

In the .dll I have done this:

```
class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        using (var db = new DB02Context())
        {
            List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

            // some queries to fill the list

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Console app I've done this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToMyDLL);
Type t = assembly.GetType("MyDLL.Models.CustomerRepository");

var methodInfo = t.GetMethod("GetAll");

if(methodInfo == null)
    throw new Exception("The method doesn't exists");

var customerRepository = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

// Invoke the GetAll() method
var customerList = methodInfo.Invoke(customerRepository, null);
```

Now the question is, since GetAll returns `IEnumerable<Customer>` and my console app
doesn't "know" anything about MyDLL.dll (I don't reference it directly, so it doesn't knows the `Customer` type).

How can I access to the Customer list in order to access Customer'a properties without having to make a reference to the .dll explicitly?

Comment: Is Customer defined in the DLL too or is that defined in your main project or a 3rd dll?

Comment: Yes, the Customer type is defined in the DLL (3rd party).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three options

1. Move `Client` or move a interface `Client` implements to a 3rd dll that both the reflected DLL and your console app can reference.
2. Use the `dynamic` keyword as the type of the object (`dynamic customerList = methodInfo.Invoke(...`), this is the exact situation it was invented for.
3. Cast the return type as a plain `IEnumerable` and use reflection calls to call the methods in `Client` on the `object` objects the `IEnumerable` returns.

Comment: Ok, using the dynamic keyword makes `customerList` to be if type IEnumerable<Customer>. Now since Customer type has a `Name` property if I try to access to this property inside of a `foreach` lopp I get a RuntimeBinderException: Object does not cantain a definition for 'Name'. I tried to access it like so inside the loop: item.Name Any advice?

Comment: Not sure, are you sure Customer has a `Name` property? Also how are you declaring your foreach loop? is it `foreach(var something in customerList)` or `foreach(dynamic something in customerList)`

Comment: It's working now. But the dynamic keyword does not provide static checking. But so far I'm leaning towards your second option answer since the other answers are a little bit vague.

Comment: Going with option 1 is the only way to get static checking of the actual `Client` class. You could "fake" static checking by making proxy classes and doing option 2 or 3 inside the proxy class like StephenM suggests in his answer, but there is no way to get real static checking without adding the dll as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

As everything is inside the DLL that you load dynamically, the first and fastest thing that comes to mind is to cast the GetAll as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and use the properties accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to make a generic IEnumerable<'Customer> object because the runtime can not statically check the properties of the class at compile time.

I was going to post about dynamic objects, but Brizio beat me to it. One other idea which might help you.

You could make a CustomerProxy class (in the console app) which exposes the public methods of customer, and invokes the Customer objects using reflection. This has the benefit of static type checking for users of the CustomerProxy class.

Comment: `You will never be able to make a IEnumerable object` -- false. You can use a non-generic one (look at `Scott Chamberlain`'s answer).

Comment: You are correct, but I meant a generic IEnumerable<Customer>. IMHO, using a non-generic collection for objects with a known type just seems like a dirty approach. Also, using plain dynamics loses static checking, which is also sub-optimal imo.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517(v=vs.100).aspx
or search for **Covariance and Contravariance in Generics**

```
IEnumerable<Object> customerList = methodInfo.Invoke(customerRepository, null);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's just a link and code, no explanation.